# C WikiBooks - How is C a small "what you see is all you get" language?

Tags: c

I'm unable to understand one of the following sentence from **WikiBooks** :

### Why C, and not assembly language?

> " C is a compiled language, which creates fast and efficient executable files. It is also a small "what you see is all you get" language: a C statement corresponds to at most a handful of assembly statements, everything else is provided by library functions. "

---

**Website Link** : [C Programming/Why learn C? - Wikibooks, open books for an open world](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Why_learn_C%3F)

**Note** : I am a complete beginner and I've started to learn C . So, I need a precise explanation of what the above sentence means.

Comment: `What you see is all you get` is taken to mean that the language does nothing for you. It only does what you ask of it, and nothing more. I.e.

Comment: @MortenJensen Can you name any other Language that is contrast to that fact?

Comment: Well, by definition languages only work according to their semantics. The point here is that the C semantics are super simple. No object instantiation, no copy constructors or implicit constructors etc., that happens "invisibly" behind your back (but of course in accordance with the language semantics) like you see in object oriented languages.

Comment: @HarishRaja , a good contrast to C's "What you see is all you get" would be Java... which allocates, deallocates and manages memory for you. C++ is also, to some extent, hiding details and implementation complexities from the developer... and these are still compiled languages which don't hide as much as scripting languages usually do. Scripting languages such as Ruby and Javascript are notorious for hiding implementation details, which is also part of why they are so easy and powerful.

Comment: ``EDIT ANSWER``: an assembler is a way to associate symbolic names for opcodes of the machine code such that the brain to think easier about it.  For example, if an instruction has a header for OPCODE and other place for operators that represent registers, addresses, etc, the assembler will associate a symbolic name such as ADD %EAX %EBX for some machine code numbers that will open and close gates such that the  result of the operation to be semantically correct.

Comment: @Myst Thank you for your precise answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assembly is the language for a single processor family, it is directly compiled to the machine code that the processor runs. If one programs in assembly, one needs to rewrite the entire code for the different processor family. Phones usually use ARM processors whereas the desktop computers have 32-bit or 64-bit x86-compatible processors. Each 3 of these potentially need a completely separately written program, and perhaps not even limited to that.

In contrast standard C is a portable language - if you write so-called strictly conforming programs. [C11 4p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p5):

> A strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the language and library specified in this International Standard. (3) It shall not produce output dependent on any unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior, and shall not exceed any minimum implementation limit.

With [footnote 5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note5) noting that:

> Strictly conforming programs are intended to be maximally portable among conforming implementations. Conforming programs may depend upon nonportable features of a conforming implementation

Unlike the assembler whose specifics vary from processor to another, it is possible to write programs in C and then *port* them to various platforms without any changes into the source code, yet these programs will still be compiled into the assembly language, and performance could - and often will - surpass hand-written assembly when using a modern high-quality optimizing compiler.

Additionally the *C standard library*, which any conforming hosted implementation needs to provide, provides for a portable way to manage files, dynamic memory, input and output, all of which are not only processor but also operating-system specific when using assembler.

However, C is still quite close to the assembly, to the extent that it has been called a "high-level assembly language" by some.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what an assembler is.

Comment: @HarishRaja then please update your *question* so that it better states what it is that you find unclear there.

Comment: @AntiiHaapala I have already mentioned in the Note section that I am a Complete Beginner.

Comment: @HarishRaja I have absolutely no idea what a complete beginner means. Obviously you know what a keyboard is, and a computer, and a programming language, and the C programming language...

Comment: OK. I include that question too. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It makes no sense to say `compiled language` and `interpreted language`.

This kind of statement are made by persons without education and could not understand the foundations of programming.

A language is defined mathematically via a way to define languages -- operational, denotational, axiomatic, etc and the programmers implement the language as they wish.

There are machines that  run C via interpretation, they dispatch the code at the moment of execution and execute it instead of accumulating some  object code that would be executed later by some machine, etc.

It is correct to say `compiled implementation`, `interpreted implementation for the language`, but even so it is relative to a given machine.  Because when you `compile` it for x86 processors, the compiled code is interpreted by the datapath and controller of a stack machine for the X86 language, etc.

Basically the statement `what you see is all you get` means that is almost 1 to 1 correspondence between the operators of the CAM defined in the abstract semantics of ISO 9899 and the current stack-machines on the market, like x86, mips, etc.

Comment: Seems like you are blaming the person who wrote that for "Wikibooks - C Programming Language".

Comment: all persons make mistakes, but, yes, this mistake is big.  And BTW, for a C beginner you should know that in C literature there are lots of dumb books, there are only about 10 books that really worth investing time on to study

Comment: Can you name the best one you feel, for a Beginner?

Comment: K&R version 2, Peter van der Linden, and in general the books printed at BellLabs by the engineers from there (there are a few), etc

Comment: I googled that and got searches for a book like this - "Expert C Programming". The name sounds like it is not for a Beginner.

Comment: read starting from my upper link.  you will be on the right way.  The book of PvdL is a must if you want to do C.

Comment: It is not correct to edit the post but start a new Question about what's an assembler.

Comment: an assembler is a way to associate symbolic names for opcodes of the machine code such that the brain to think easier about it, but you need to open a new thread of discussion as it's another topic.

Comment: Thanks you, so much.

Comment: I answered you to comments as it is not conforming to the rules of SO to mix the subjects in the same thread, etc.

Comment: I am sorry but your are wrong. The C standard defines the way the source shall be processed to produce an executable file. It is legal to use a function that will be defined later in the code provided it has been forward declared. This makes no sense in an interpreted environment. So yes the standard defines C as a compiled language

Comment: @SergeBallesta In an interpreted environment it is scanned 2 times to detect first forward definitions, etc.

Comment: If it is scanned 2 times, it must have a notion of translation unit which is a compiler notion. Python or ruby are interpreted languages in the sense where you can pass commands to an interpreter that processes them one at a time - so definition must come before usage. Of course you can compile Python, but you cannot find an interactive interpreter for C.

Comment: @SergeBallesta there are interpreters for C.  I bow out from here now.

Comment: Nothing in the standard says what should be the result of the processing of source files. It could be interpretable bytecodes that could be usable on any architecture (Java which is a also compiled language is processed that way). But that initial processing is indeed a compilation phase.

Comment: "This kind of statement are made by persons without education and could not understand the foundations of programming." This is just provocative nonsense. Sure, you can write a C interpreter, but C is typically used as a _compiled_ language. There is a language-nerd sense in which _compiled_ vs _interpreted_ has no meaning; but there is also a common usage sense in which it does. [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136993/interpreted-vs-compiled-a-useful-distinction) is some discussion on the matter.

Comment: @alinsoar: I have not been offensive, and have tried to present facts, so please do not ask me to learn C! I even know [Ch shell](http://www.softintegration.com/docs/ch/shell/) that is indeed an interpreted shell with C syntax. But AFAIK, even if the syntax is C, it is not a conformant C implementation because you can imagine a valid C program that you cannot use is Ch (forward declaration). So Ch shell is an interpreted *variant* of C. If you know a conformant C interpreter, please share you knowledge here.

Answer (score 2):

C is nothing more than a platform-independent Assembly translator, what you write in C is efficiently "translated" into machine code as it would if you write it directly in Assembly. Thats the point of:

> "what you see is all you get" language: a C statement corresponds to at most a handful of assembly statements

Any C sentence you write is directly transformed to ASM by the compiler without abstraction layers, interpreters, etc, unlike other languages.

By definition, C is tinny, it has nothing but the esentials to be considered a [turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) language and nothing more. Any additional feature is achieved via libraries, C ships the std lib (diferent implementations tho) that packs things like RNG, memory management, etc.

That's what this means:

> everything else is provided by library functions

Comment: I'm sorry but that was only true for old versions of C like K&R C. The same C instruction can be translated in very different ways, or even optimized out at compilation depending on the context. C used to be a *"what you see is all you get" language* but is no longer.

Comment: @SergeBallesta you are right, by C im talking about original ANSI and pre ANSI C, covering by this definition C89 and C99, that's the "original" C language and the base for everything else, i'm not even remotely talking about C11 here. Maybe the key world in my answer is "simplification", i tryied to condensate the entire philosophical stuff in a book (K&R) in just one post, and, as you can see, it could be missleading in a certain way, im sorry. Anyways, i think my answer is clear enough to solve the OP's question without being too complex or technical.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old and largely outdated claim about C.

C was originally designed as, roughly, a more readable and portable assembler.   For this reason, most of the core language features tended - on most target machines - to be easily translated.     Generally more complicated functionality was provided by library functions, including the standard library.

Over time, C (both the language and the standard library) have evolved, and become more complicated.   Computing hardware has also become more complicated - for example, supporting a set of more advanced instructions - and C constructs which can be implemented in terms of advanced instructions will translate to more complicated assembler on machines that support older and simpler instruction sets.

The distinction between a "small" language and a "large" one is completely subjective - so some people still continue to describe C as small and simple, both others describe is as large and complex.   While simpler than some other languages (like C++), C is now also significantly more complex - by various measures - than quite a few other programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

This quote is absolutely true for the good old K&R C implementation of the 70'. In this old days, C was indeed a thin wrapper around machine instructions, and the programmer could easily guess how the compiler would translate the source:

- for loop: a counter in appropriate register, a test at end of loop a goto
- function call: push arguments to the stack (with no conversion!), call the sub-routine address. On return put the return value (required to be scalar or pointer) to the appropriate register and use machine return. On return, the caller cleans up the stack

On a symetric point of view, anything that could be executed by the processor could be expressed in C. If you have an array of two integers and know that the internal representation is a valid double, just cast a pointer and use it.

That's all wrong with recent version of the C language and with optimizing compilers. The *as if* rule allows the optimizer to do anything, **provided the observable results are what a natural implementation should have given**. Many operations can invoke Undefined Behaviour. For example writing a float at a memory location and using it as an integer is explicitely UB. The optimizer can assume that no UB exists in the program, so it can just optimize out any block containing UB (recent versions of gcc are great at that).

Look for example at this function:

```
void stopit() {
   int i = 0;
   while(1) {
      i+=1;
   }
   printf("done");
}
```

It contains an infinite loop, so the printf should never be reached. But the loop has no observable result, so the compiler is free to optimize it out and translate it the same as:

```
void stopit() {
   printf("done");
}
```

Another example

```
int i = 12;
float *f = &i;
*f = 12.5;              // UB use an float variable to access an int
printf("0x%04x\n", i);  // try to dump the representation of 12.5
```

This code can legally display `0x000c`, because the compiler is free to assume that the `*f=0.` has not modified `i`, so it can directly use a cached value and translate the last line directly as `printf("0x%04x\n", 12);`

So not, recent versions of the C language are no longer *a small "what you see is all you get" language*

---

What is true is that C is a low level language. The programmer has full control on allocation/deallocation of dynamic storage. You have a natural access at the byte level for any type, you have the notion of pointer and explicit pointer/integer conversion to allow direct access to well known memory addresses. That indeed allows to program embedded systems or micro-controller in C. The standard even defines two environment levels: a hosted environment where you have full access to the standard library and a freestanding environment where the standard library is not present. This can be specifically interesting for systems with very little memory.

Answer (score 1):

C provides low-level control of memory and resources at the byte and bit level.  For example C and assembly language are very common in the programming of microcontrollers (my area of expertise), which have very little memory and most often require bit-level control of input and output ports.

If you write a C program and build it, then look at your listing file, you'll typically see the very close correspondence between your C statements and the few assembly instructions into which the C is assembled.

Another clue to its simplicity is to look at its grammar definition as compared to that for C# or Java or Python, for example.  The C grammar is small, terse, compact compared to the "fuller" languages, and it's true, there isn't even input or output defined in C.  That typically comes from including `stdio.h` or similar.  In this way, you only get what you need in your executable.  That is in start contrast to the "big" languages.

While many in the embedded (microcontroller) programming space still prefer assembly, C is a great way to abstract **a little bit** things like flow of control and pointers, while still retaining the power to employ practically every instruction the microprocessor or microcontroller is capable of.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "what you see is all you get" statement...

C is a "small" language in that provides only a handful of *abstractions* - that is, high-level language constructs that either hide implementation-specific details (such as I/O, type representations, address representations, etc.) or simplify complex operations (memory management, event processing, etc.).  C doesn't provide any support at the language level (either in the grammar or standard library) for things like networking, graphics, sound, etc.; you must use separate, third-party libraries for those tasks, which will vary based on platform (Windows, MacOS, iOS, Linux).  Compare that to a language like Java, which provides a class library for just about *everything* you could ever want to do.

Compared to languages like C++ and Java, not a whole lot of things happen "under the hood" in C.  There's no overloading of functions or operators, there are no constructors or destructors that are automatically called when objects are created or destroyed, there's no real support for "generic" programming (writing a function template that can be automatically instantiated for arguments of different types), etc.  Because of this, it's often easier to predict how a particular piece of code will perform.

There's no automatic resource management in C - arrays don't grow or shrink as you add or remove elements, there's no automatic garbage collection that reclaims dynamic memory that you aren't using anymore, etc.

The only container provided by the C language is the array - for anything more complex (lists, trees, queues, stacks, etc.) you have to write your own implementation, or use somebody else's library.

C is "close to the machine" in that the types and abstractions it provides are based on what real-world hardware provides.  For example, integer and floating-point representations and operations are based on what the native hardware supports.  The size of an `int` is (usually) based on the native CPU's word size, meaning it can only represent a certain range of values (the minimum range required by the language standard is `[-32767..32767]` for signed integers and `[0..65535]` for unsigned integers).  Operations on `int` objects are mapped to native `ADD/DIV/MUL/SUB` opcodes. Languages like Python provide "arbitrary precision" types, which are not limited by what the hardware can natively support - the tradeoff is that operations using these types are often slower, since you're not using native opcodes.